# Check the difference between two count() in the same table

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the difference between two `counts()` in the same table depending on date.

In my case results for 2020.01.15 and 2020.01.14 could have a different number of rows i.e

```
for 2020.01.14  for 2020.01.15 
test1 50          test1 -
test2 250         test3 330
test3 330         test 5
test4 -           test3 5
test5 451         test5 670
test6 -           test6 55
test7 44          test3 -
```

I tried something like

```
SELECT 
    a.type AS type1, a.result AS result1, a.check, COUNT(a.id), 
    b.type, b.result, b.check, COUNT(b.id)
FROM 
    database AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    database AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE 
    a.country = 'BY' 
    AND a.result IN ('X', 'Y', 'OK') 
    AND a.time BETWEEN '2021-01-14 00:00:01 AND '2021-01-15 00:00:01' 
    AND b.time > '2021-01-15 00:00:01' 
    AND a.result = b.result 
    AND a.type = b.type
GROUP BY
    a.type, a.result, a.check, b.type, b.result, b.type;
```

but it still returns the same numbers for count(a.id) and count(b.id) so in case I do `count(a.id) - count(b.id)` I always get 0 despite the fact that once I run queries separately they return different numbers.

What I need is to get the difference for each row:

```
i.e 
test1 -50
test2 80
test3 -325
test4 -5
etc....
```

Comment: Please provide sample data.  It is quite unclear what your *original* table looks like.  In addition, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: **Bad habits to kick** : [using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)